# How to populate a new table with data from two other tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've got a database which I need to alter.
The original database consists of 3 tables.
It now needs to be extended with one more table.

The data for the new table come from two tables of the original database.
I can create the table but I can't populate it with the data.
The original tables are:

```
create table Accommodatie
(plaatscode       varchar(3)  not null,
 accommodatienr   numeric(3)  not null,
 accommodatiename varchar(25) not null,
 adres            varchar(25) not null,
 plaatsnaam       varchar(20) not null,
 land             varchar(20) not null,
 email            varchar(30) null,
 internet         varchar(30) null,
 contactpersoon   varchar(25) null,
 primary key (plaatscode, accommodatienr));

create table Vervoer
(vervoercode    numeric(5)   not null,
 plaatscode     varchar(3)   not null,
 stedenadviseur varchar(20)  not null,
 vervoersoort   varchar(12)  not null,
 maatschappij   varchar(15)  not null,
 omschrijving   varchar(50)  not null,
 overstap       varchar(30)  null,
 primary key (vervoercode));

create table Vervoerprijs
(vervoercode  numeric(5)    not null,
 seizoen      varchar(6)    not null,
 prijs        numeric(6,2)  not null,
 plaatscode   varchar(3)    not null,
 primary key (vervoercode, seizoen),
 foreign key (vervoercode) references Vervoer(vervoercode));
```

The new table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Plaatscode
(   plaatscode      varchar(3)  not null,
    stedenadviseur  varchar(20) not null,
    land            varchar(20) not null,
    PRIMARY KEY (plaatscode));
```

For the new table I need `plaatscode` and `land` from `Accommodatie` and `vervoerscode` from the table `vervoer`.

Can you help me to build a query to populate the new table?

Comment: When talking about 3 *columns* that the original databases consists of, as well as one *column* it needs to be extended with, do you actually mean "3 *tables*", "one *table*"?

Comment: Excuse when I talked about colums I meant tables. I'm dutch so excuse me.
From the table accommodatie the column land and plaatscode need to be stores in a new table named Pllatscode from the table Vervoer the colum stedenadviseur needs to be stored in the table Plaatscode

Comment: I've edited your question in an attempt to clarify it a bit. Could you please take a look at the modified version to verify that everything's right? If something isn't, please feel free to roll back my changes and/or add your own (using the *Edit* link under the post).

Comment: @AndriyM That looks better, Thanks. The solution was simpler than I thought of. Just joining... My teacher will kill me If he know this.. ;) Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If all you want to do is populate your new table, the following should work:

```
INSERT INTO Plaatscode
(
  plaatscode,
  stedenadviseur,
  land
)
SELECT
a.plaatscode, v.stedenadviseur, a.land
FROM Accommodatie a
INNER JOIN Vervoer
ON a.plaatscode = v.plaatscode
```